# Databound UI Not Updating

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have implemented an ObserveableCollection of "Contact" Objects on a page and set it as the itemsource for a longlistselector.  All the properties of the "Contact" Objects implement INotifyPropertyChanged.  The List and properties display fine once they are added to the ObserveableCollection.  However, whenever I change one of the properties in code the change is not reflected in the UI till I leave the page and return.  Therefore the databound properties don't update in realtime.

From XAML Page:

```
public ObservableCollection<Contact> contacts = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();

Contact[] data = ContactHandler.Singleton().GetContacts().Values.OrderBy(x => x.DisplayName.ToLower()[0]).ToArray();
        int dataCount = data.Length;

        this.LayoutRoot.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < data.Length; x++)
            {
                contacts.Add(data[x]);
            }
});
```

Here is where I Update the "Highlight" property of the "contacts":

```
private void contactList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Contact contact = contactList.SelectedItem as Contact;

        if (contact != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(contact.DisplayName + " is: " + contact.Highlight);

            string uid = contact.UserID;
            if (uids.Contains(uid))
            {
                uids.Remove(uid);
                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    contact.Highlight = Visibility.Collapsed;
                });
            }
            else
            {
                uids.Add(uid);
                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    contact.Highlight = Visibility.Visible;
                });
            }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I'm an idiot.

Lession learned.  Never forget to have your object in the collection (in my case Contact) inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged.  I was implementing it but not inheriting.